# tmpConstructor empty in Java Class.newInstance()

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, constructor

I have tracked down an error to line 362 of the java.lang.Class class:

```
Constructor<T> tmpConstructor = cachedConstructor;
```

The variable does not seem to get assigned. In the debug expression windows it only says "tmpConstructor cannot be resolved to a variable". The cachedConstructor is not null.

An error is only thrown further down when a the newInstance() function is called:

```
try {
       return tmpConstructor.newInstance((Object[])null);
    } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {                      
       Unsafe.getUnsafe().throwException(e.getTargetException());
        // Not reached
        return null;
    }
```

Context:
Using JSON Plugin with the Struts2 framework to create Java objects from the received JSON.
The field it is trying to parse is a subclass of an abstract class.

On further inspection (thanks to user902838) I was missing that it can't instantiate an abstract class. So I need to find out how it can instantiate subclasses, which is a different question.

Can someone please explain to me why the tmpconstructor is empty?

Comment: Can you add some context? This might just be a limitation of your debugger.

Comment: Not being assigned is different than not able to be resolved. You need to provide some context about what you're talking about.

Comment: from java docs `* @exception InvocationTargetException if the  nderlying constructor throws an exception.`

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell without any information about the class you're trying to instantiate or the exception/error you observe, but my best guess would be that the class does not have a nullary constructor.  This program exhibits such a problem:

```
package example;

public class NewInstanceTest {

    public NewInstanceTest(String s) {
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Class.forName("example.NewInstanceTest").newInstance();
    }

}
```

The problem can be fixed by adding a nullary constructor:

```
package example;

public class NewInstanceTest {

    /* nullary constructor: */
    public NewInstanceTest() {
        this("default");
    }

    public NewInstanceTest(String s) {
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Class.forName("example.NewInstanceTest").newInstance();
    }

}
```

or by removing all non-nullary constructors so that Java will provide a nullary one automatically:

```
package example;

public class NewInstanceTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Class.forName("example.NewInstanceTest").newInstance();
    }

}
```